# Como fazer paginação com AngularJS e php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Como se faz paginação com angular e php?

Meu php:

```
<?php
include_once("conPDO.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$buscaCidades=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cidade");
$buscaCidades->execute();

$return = array();

while ($linha=$buscaCidades->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return[] = array(
        'idCidade'  => $linha['idCidade'],
        'nome'  => utf8_encode($linha['nome']),
    );
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Meu html:

```
<div align="center">
<table width="400">
    <tr>
        <td width="200"><b>Cidade</b></td>
        <td width="100"><b>Sala</b></td>
        <td width="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cidade in cidades">
        <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{cidade.sala}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Meu controller:

```
app.controller("CidadesController", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {

var carregaCidades = function () {
    $http.get("admin/php/pegaCidades.php").success(function (data){
        //console.log(data);
        $scope.cidades = data;
    });
};

carregaCidades();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que utilize uma das varias diretivas existentes no mercado.

Eu particularmente achei essa exceptional!

[Pagine quase tudo em AngularJS !](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs)

Como usar:

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="item in items | itemsPerPage: 10"></li>
</ul>

// Em algoum outro lugar na pagina ....

<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: +1, desconhecia essa maneira. Estava fazendo tudo na mão :l

Answer (score 0):

Aqui explico como fazer: https://guerrati.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/angularjs-paginacao-no-ng-repeat/

Basicamente é assim:

Utiliza o [dirPaginate](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination). Você precisa baixálo [aqui](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js), depois iniciá-lo na sua página:

```
<script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
```

E colocá-lo como dependência do seu módulo principal:

```
var app = angular.module('guerraTI', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Agora para ativar a paginação, basta substituir o ng-repeat pela diretiva dir-paginate. O único parâmetro que precisa ser adicionado é o itemsPerPage, que como o próprio nome já diz, é a quantidade de registros que serão mostrados em cada página.

```
<tr dir-paginate="dado in dados|filter:procurar|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|itemsPerPage:5">
```

Após isso, pode colocar os controles da paginação:

```
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
```